# Force a URL to open in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpart on a site that allows you to insert a "Show more" link to an external page that expands on the information displayed in the webpart. Unfortunately this option only takes a regular URL as the value for the link, it doesn't let you construct the HTML link itself. I need this link to open in a new tab but since I only get to put the URL in, I can't use the normal `target="_blank"` HTML code. Is there a way to craft the URL itself to force a new tab?

Comment: Can you use javascript or jquery ?

Comment: No. You'll need to be able to modify or add some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript:

```
   window.open("url");
```

Or adding the attr:

```
   document.getElementById("theLink").setAttribute("target", "_blank");
```

With the following html

```
   <a id="theLink" href="url">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot modify any part the `a` tag, you can use `jquery`.
The following script will **try** to open all links on a different tab/window:

```
$("a").on("click",function(){
       event.preventDefault();
       window.open($(this).attr('href'),'_blank');
});
```

---

**NOTE:**

Make sure you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23415303/797495)